# Gurobi: how to add a constraint to make there be only one non-integer value

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint, gurobi

|  | line1 | line2 | line3 | line4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2.3 | 0 | 3.1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 4 | 2.2 | 0 |
| C | 1.1 | 0 | 0 | 4.6 |

Let's say after optimization with certain constraints, my model will generate an optimal production allocation table similar to above. A, B, C are the three product types and the matrix displays the number of hours needed for each production line in order to finish the demand.

I need to add another constraint which allows only one non-integer hour amount for each of the products. what is the easiest way or logic to do this? Please show by model.addVars() and model.addConstrs() if possible.

Update:
This is what I wrote according to the answer by Rob:

```
y = edm.addVars(lines, products, vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
z = edm.addVars(lines, products, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
for line in lines:
    for product in products:
        constraint1_1 = edm.addConstr(
            (
              #blocks[line, product] - y[line, product] >= - z[line, product]
              y[line, product] - blocks[line, product] <= z[line, product]
            ), 
            name = 'constraint 1.1'
        )
        
        constraint1_2 = edm.addConstr(
            (
              blocks[line, product] - y[line, product] <= z[line, product]
            ), 
            name = 'constraint 1.2'
        )

constraint2 = edm.addConstrs(
    (
      quicksum(z[line, product] for line in lines) <= 1 for product in products
      ),
    name = 'constraint 2'
    )
```

But my model optimization keeps running and has not given a solution for 2 hours. Any ideas what could be the issue? Thanks

Comment: It might help to add explicit bounds on $y$.

Answer (score 11):

Let $x_{p,\ell}$ be the continuous variables in your table.  Introduce integer variables $y_{p,\ell}$ and binary variables $z_{p,\ell}$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
-z_{p,\ell} \le x_{p,\ell} - y_{p,\ell} &\le z_{p,\ell} &&\text{for all $p$ and $\ell$} \tag1 \\
\sum_\ell z_{p,\ell} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $p$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $x_{p,\ell} \not= y_{p,\ell} \implies z_{p,\ell} = 1$.  Constraint $(2)$ allows this to happen at most once per $p$.

If your solver supports indicator constraints, you can replace $(1)$ with $z_{p,\ell} = 0 \implies x_{p,\ell} = y_{p,\ell}$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. If you don't mind could you check my code above

Comment: With respect to solve time, can you post log or any details on solver stats?